# my ggplot does not appear using R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I don't know why my ggplot does not appear when I run my app. It appears using plot, it works. But using ggplot, nothing appears. No graph! I tried with `print()` and without it, no result.

My app I import an csv file and from it I plot a graph.
Could you help me, please?

# Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # added "session" because updateSelectInput requires it

  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1) # require that the input is available

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)


  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                    choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)])
  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                    choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)])

  return(df)

  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]

   p <- ggplot(x, aes(input$xcol,input$ycol)) 
   p <- p + geom_line() #+ geom_point()
   print(p)


    # plot(mydata, type = "l",
    #      xlab = input$xcol,
    #      ylab = input$ycol)
  })

  # Generate a summary table of the data uploaded
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    y <- data()
    summary(y)

  })

}

# Create Shiny app
shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where is your ui.R?  You don't need `print()`. Changing the last line to `p` will return it, but I'm not sure if that will solve everything because I can't see your ui code.

Comment: This is correct, if a function does not include a return statement the last line in the function is considered the return

Comment: ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Upload File",
           titlePanel("Uploading Files"), 
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               fileInput(inputId = "file1", label = "Choose CSV File",multiple = FALSE, accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values, text/plain",".csv") ),
  tabPanel("Plot",
           pageWithSidebar(
             headerPanel("Plot your data"),
             sidebarPanel(selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', ""),
               selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = "")),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput('MyPlot'))

Comment: @AdamBirenbaum, please above my ui.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues in your code: `input$xcol` and `input$ycol` are holding character values, therefore you must use `aes_string` in the `ggplot` function. Also, you needed to get your `tabsetPanel` and `sidebarLayout` straight (minor issue).

Other than that, in your `data` reactive, you use inputs for `sep` and `quote` which are not found in your UI, causing an error. If I comment them out, everything is working as expected. For testing I used `write.csv(diamonds, file = "diamonds.csv")`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

      fileInput(
        inputId = "file1",
        label = "Choose CSV File",
        multiple = FALSE,
        accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")
      )),

      tabPanel(
        "Plot",
        pageWithSidebar(
          headerPanel("Plot your data"),
          sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("xcol", "X Variable", ""),
            selectInput("ycol", "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
          ),
          mainPanel(plotOutput("MyPlot"))
        )
      )))

  ,

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # added "session" because updateSelectInput requires it

    data <- reactive({
      req(input$file1) # require that the input is available

      df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)#,
      # no such inputs in your UI
      #   header = input$header,
      #   sep = input$sep,
      #   quote = input$quote
      # )


      updateSelectInput(session,
        inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
        choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
      )
      updateSelectInput(session,
        inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
        choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
      )

      return(df)
    })

    output$contents <- renderTable({
      data()
    })

    output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
      x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]

      p <- ggplot(x, aes_string(input$xcol, input$ycol))
      p <- p + geom_line() #+ geom_point()
      print(p)

      # plot(mydata, type = "l",
      #      xlab = input$xcol,
      #      ylab = input$ycol)
    })

    # Generate a summary table of the data uploaded
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
      y <- data()
      summary(y)
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! it was very helpful!